# Is anyone running product retargeting ads? If so, through what provider?

Tags: extensions

Does anyone have experience with using any of the retargeting platforms with their Magento store that they could share? We're interested in doing some retargeting to bring customers who have browsed back, but aren't sure which provider to go with. Any pros/cons/gotchas would be super helpful, as well as any data on efficacy. We're a little concerned that simple "hey, come back to our site" retargeting is a waste of time and money, but would love to hear from someone that's implemented it on their store before we jump to conclusions.

Comment: I think this is a bit off topic an a bit opinion based. For me, this question is not really about magento. It is more about bringing people back to any website. Everyone wants people to come back.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you feel that way. I believe it's quite specific and disagree with you. Bringing previous shoppers back to an ecommerce site to convert them on a specific product is very different from just bringing any users back generically. That generic retargeting is what we're trying to avoid and thus want to understand how to best do product-level targeting in Magento.

Comment: The problem with this question is, that it opens for a lot of advertisement and therefore I think on the long run the answers might be more bad with time. For this moment I would leave it open... But I agree with Marius.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about marketing in general.

Comment: It is very relevant but you're not going to get very much here as these are tech forums, you can post it over here http://www.warriorforum.com/ecommerce-sites-wholesaling-drop-shipping/ and we can have a business discussion about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Dynamic Product Ads.

Install the google analytics universal tracking code with the walkthrough here if you haven't already done so:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229312/universal-analytics-could-not-track-transaction-in-magento

Then add all of your products to your google merchant account.  It dynamically shows relevant products that they've already viewed (if setup right).  You can further segment and change your spend based on what type of customer they are (spend more for people that made it to your cart page for example...or offer them an ad with a coupon.)

Our experience has been excellent...and it says a lot more than just "Hey man come back to our site"

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your answer. Do you serve the Dynamic Product Ads just on google.com or do you buy on their network (i.e. displayed on third party sites) as well?

Comment: Use dynamic product ads all over the place.  Remarketing on their 3rd party display network still has really high ROI since the traffic is so targeted (at least from our experience.)

Comment: That being said, we only use the search network for traditional adwords and not 3rd party sites~